# How to calculate time-difference in pandas with NaN-values

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I´m relatively new to Pandas and tried the search already, but I couldn´t find a solution.
I have a dataframe with Transaction-No., customerId and the date of purchase which looks like this:

```
Transaction   12345    12346       12347     12348       12349
customerID
1             NaN    2019-09-01    NaN     2019-09-11      2019-09-22...
2           2019-10-01 NaN         NaN         NaN      2019-10-07...
3    ...
```

The dataframe has [6334 rows x 8557 columns].
Every row has NaN-values, as the Transaction-No. is unique.

I would like to calculate the date difference for each row so I get

```
customerID    Datedifference1    Datedifference2     etc.
1                10                    11
2                 6
3   ...
```

I´m struggling to get a list with the datedifferences for every customerId.
Is there a way to ignore NaN in the dataframe and to only calculate on the values that are not NaN?
I would like to have a list with customerId and the datediff between purchase 1 and 2, 2 and 3, etc. to estimate the days until the next purchase will occur.

Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is reshape data by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then get differences, remove first missing values per groups and reshape back:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)

df1 = (df.stack()
         .groupby(level=0)
         .diff()
         .dropna()
         .dt.days
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .to_frame())

df1 = (df1.set_index(df1.groupby(['customerID']).cumcount(), append=True)[0]
          .unstack()
          .add_prefix('Datedifference'))
print (df1)
             Datedifference0  Datedifference1
Transaction                                  
1                       10.0             11.0
2                        6.0              NaN
```

EDIT: If input data are different, solution is changed - convert column to datetimes, create new column by [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) for differencies, remove only `NaN` rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and last reshape with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and `unstack` with counter `Series` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
print (df1)
   customerID Transaction       date
0           1       12346 2019-09-01
1           1       12348 2019-09-11
2           1       12349 2019-09-22
3           2       12345 2019-10-01
4           2       12349 2019-10-07

df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1['diff'] = df1.groupby('customerID')['date'].diff().dt.days
df1 = df1.dropna(subset=['diff'])

df2 = (df1.set_index(['customerID', df1.groupby('customerID').cumcount()])['diff']
          .unstack()
          .add_prefix('Datedifference'))
print (df2)
            Datedifference0  Datedifference1
customerID                                  
1                      10.0             11.0
2                       6.0              NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I´ll check the stack documentation to get a brief idea about it, but your suggestion throws KeyError: 'Transaction'. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @miner - How working if use `customerID` instead `Transaction` ?

Comment: Is there a way to calculate on columns in pandas? The data source is a csv file with Transaction, customerId and date so that I have all transactions in a single row. But that means, that I have e.g. 20 rows with customerId 123 and different Transaction-No. and dates

Comment: @miner - Not understand, expected output is different? Can you edit expected output in question?

Comment: no, the expected output is as discribed in my question. But the initial datasource is a csv-file that has the coulumns 'Transaction', 'customerId' and 'Date'. The sample has almost 20k rows with one row for each transaction.

Comment: @miner - Ok, can you add data sample of input file, first 5 rows?

Comment: here are the first 5 rows.                                                                                                  
        Transaction  customerId        Date
    0        42708        6214  2018-10-01
    1        42709       27466  2018-10-01
    2        42710       26676  2018-10-01
    3        42711       22002  2018-10-01
    4        42712       26399  2018-10-01                                                                                Your update throws TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' ??

Comment: @miner - Use `df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])` before my second update, answer was edited.

Comment: That´s what I was searching for! Thank you very much.